# How to let gpg-agent confirm each key usage

Tags: gnupg

When running `gpg-agent` as part of my login session each program I run has access to my (possibly) unlocked PGP-key. It might be paranoid, but I want to get confirmation about each key usage, so I wish for an option to `gpg-agent` that when the passphrase or card pin is already cached it pops up a confirmation dialog before allowing access to the key.

For ssh-keys managed by `gpg-agent` such an option exists according to the [manpage](http://www.dsm.fordham.edu/cgi-bin/man-cgi.pl?topic=gpg-agent&ampsect=1), but not for PGP.

Did I miss something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no option which simply displays a message. In the end, you've got to choose from two options:

1. **Disable the cache completely**, to make sure the passphrase is not stored at all:

   ```
   --max-cache-ttl n
         Set the maximum time a cache entry is valid to n seconds.  After
         this time a cache entry will be expired  even  if  it  has  been
         accessed  recently  or has been set using gpg-preset-passphrase.
         The default is 2 hours (7200 seconds).
   ```

   I'm not sure if a value of `0` disables the cache completely or sets the maximum time to infinite -- you will easily be able to find out. Setting it to `1` seconds should probably be fine, either.
2. There is an option to **disable the cache when signing** (while decryption still uses it):

   ```
   --ignore-cache-for-signing
         This option will let gpg-agent bypass the passphrase  cache  for
         all  signing  operation.   Note that there is also a per-session
         option to control this behaviour but this  command  line  option
         takes precedence.
   ```

   The idea behind this is to prevent accidentally signing a message (which possibly cannot be undone), while accidentally decrypting a message probably won't do harm.

If considering these options, think about what attack you want to mitigate. If anybody is able to perform actions with your key, he's very likely able to run arbitrary commands anyway and might well install a trojan or key logger.

Comment: "If anybody is able to perform actions with your key, he's very likely able to run arbitrary commands anyway and might well install a trojan or key logger." <-- This is not necessarily the case when the GPG agent connection is forwarded to remote connection, then this extra layer of protection makes more sense.

Comment: You're right -- this can pretty well be compared with using a key on a crypto smartcard, that performs all (public-private-key) cryptographic operations in place of the main processor.